# C# class polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Why the result of the fallowing code is:

> Class A
>   Class A
>   Class A

```
public class A {
    public virtual void f() {
        Console.WriteLine("Class A");
    }
}
public class B : A {
    public virtual void f() {
        Console.WriteLine("Class B");
    }
}
public class C : B {
    public override void f() {
        Console.WriteLine("Class C");
    }
}
//...
static void Main(string[] args) {
    A[] array = new A[3];
    array[0] = new A();
    array[1] = new B();
    array[2] = new C();
    for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++)
        array[d].f();
}
```

Comment: if this is a homework question put the "homework" tag please

Comment: Result isn't `A A A`, its `Class A Class A Class A`.

Comment: It's not a homework, i read it in a book and i did not understand why that result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because `virtual` does not equals to `override`. By using `virtual` keyword you essentially creating new method, which is virtual but it is new to your class(class B) and does not override class's A method. Class C which is inherited from B doesn't know about class's A method f() so it takes B.f() to override it. And in the Main method you are creating an array of A classes where only A.f() method exists.
If you want

```
Class A  
Class B  
Class C
```

output use `override` instead of `virtual` in class B.

Comment: I think he is asking why does he gets `A A A` as an output.

Answer (score 0):

AAA because

```
A[] array = new A[3]; /*main reference to A object*/
```