# C# - Polymorphism of classes inside array

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am trying to utlise polymorphism for class instances inside an Object array:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
ClassB b = new ClassB();

Object[] classes = new Object[] { a, b };
```

An example of one of the classes would be:

```
public class ClassA 
{
    public string PrintOutput()
    {
        return "254,62,455,5,15,62,656";
    }
}
```

I've tried something similar to: [C# class polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078343/c-sharp-class-polymorphism)

The issue this person had was that they created an array of type A (one of the classes). Changing the array type to Object leads to the error: object not containing a definition for the method/no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type object could be found.

EDIT: At the moment, I'm just trying to print the outputs from the method in each class:

```
foreach (Object obj in classes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.PrintOutput());
}
```

obj.PrintOutput() is where I get the above error.

Comment: Did you consider using and interface that all your classes would implement?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you trying to enumerate the `classes` and call method or what? Can you show the code which doesn't work and the error you get?

Comment: @Sinatr Edited the question to show where I get the error. Basically just trying to enumerate the classes at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is using common interface

```
public interface IPrintOutput
{
    string PrintOutput();
}

public class ClassA : IPrintOutput
{
    public string PrintOutput()
    {
         return "254,62,455,5,15,62,656";
    }
}

public class ClassB : IPrintOutput
{
    public string PrintOutput()
    {
         return "something else";
    }
}

IPrintOutput[] classes = new IPrintOutput[] { a, b };
```

Second way you can override ToString and use it (every object has ToString)

Answer (score 2):

A common interface is the best solution.
Another solution is define classes as dynamic:

```
 dynamic[] classes = new Object[] { a, b };
```